# Unable to access cqlsh, running cassandra on aws EC2

Tags: amazon-ec2, cassandra, cqlsh

I am running cassandra on Ec2 instance, while accessing cqlsh I am getting following error.

Pls suggest.

[Click this to see the image of error log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/39fU3.png)

Comment: cqlsh requires additional parameters like hostip (unless 127.0.0.1), port (unless default 9042), username/password (if auth) is configured. Your screenshot doesn't seem to have any of this value

Comment: yeah that's a good point..will check

Answer (score 0):

Did you update kernel settings to increase number of threads/file handles? Error looks like you hit max threads system wide. https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/5.1/dse-admin/datastax_enterprise/config/configRecommendedSettings.html has good recommendations.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your python version. Since 2.2 , your python version should be greater than 2.6 for cqlsh to work.